# Laravel 5 alternative calling controller from the router

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I need to show three pages, depending of request parameters.
Now it is realised like in the docs :

This is idea, I omit some of code

Route:

```
Route::get('/home/{mode}', 'ModeController@show');
```

Controller :

```
switch (mode) {
  case 0 : // gather the data set 1
            return View::make("View one", compact('data set1'))
  case 1 : // gather the data set 2
            return View::make("View two", compact('data set2'))
  case 2 : // gather the data set 3
            return View::make("View three", compact('data set3))
}
```

Sure, controller got thick and stupid.
I'd like realize that like this

Route :
  1. Analyze mode parameter
  2. Call controller, depends of mode

Controller :
  Gather data and calling view

Is it possible ?

Comment: please share the full method not only `switch ` case part.

Answer (score 0):

Well, solution is as here :
In web.php

```
Route::get('data', 'data@show')->name('data.show');

Route::get('/', function (request $request) {


if (isset($request->mode)) {  
    $mode_prm = $request->mode;
} else {
    $mode_prm = 0;
}

switch ($mode_prm) {        
    case 0 :
        return redirect()->route('data.show');
    case 1 :
    //and so on
```

});

Controller :

class data extends Controller
{
    //

```
 public function show(request $request){
    //gather and perform data into data set for the view 
    return view('data', compact(data_set));
}
```

}

I don't know if that solution is beautiful, but it works.
Hope it helps to someone.